# rails, request via ajax, catch a success

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have following:

```
<%= text_field_tag 'group_name','',:placeholder => "#{t "placeholder_group_name"}", :class => "group_name" %>
```

I want to send a request via ajax with a value of a 'group_name' to an action group_name_exists and then render a success => false and change class 'group_name' to red.

ajax:

```
<script>
$( function() {

$( ".group_name" ).on("onchange",function(e) {
      $.ajax({
    url: '<%= group_name_exists_groups_path %>', 

    data: {group_name: $(this).val}, 
    success: function(response) {
        if (response.key)
            alert(response.key);
    }

    });
});
});
</script>

  def group_name_exists
    blabla

     respond_to do |format|  
     format.html  
     logger.info "jjj #{group.as_json()}"
     format.json { render :json => { :success => false} }

  end
```

However he is telling me the following error:

```
An ActionView::MissingTemplate occurred in groups#group_name_exists:

Parameters: {"group_name"=>"undefined", "action"=>"group_name_exists", "controller"=>"groups", "locale"=>"en"}
```

It seems that I accessed the text in `text_field_tag` wrongly by typing `$(this).val`. Hoe can I access a text in text_field_tag with a class 'group_name'?

**edit:** (respond_to)

```
<div id="content">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$( function() {
$( ".group_name" ).on("onchange",function(e) {
    $.ajax({
    url: '<%= group_name_exists_groups_path %>',    
    data: {group_name: $(this).val()}, 
    success: function(){
      alert('success');
                       },
    error: function(){
      alert('failure');
                       }

    });
});
});
</script>

<%= text_field_tag 'group_name','',:placeholder => "#{t "placeholder_group_name"}", :class => "group_name" %>       
</div>


 def group_name_exists
     logger.info "giveHint #{params}"
     group_name = params[:group_name]
     group = Group.find_by_sql("SELECT DISTINCT gk1 FROM groups WHERE gk1 = '#{group_name}';")   
     if group.empty?
       succ = false         
     else
       succ = true
     end

     respond_to do |format|
       format.js { render :json => {:success => succ}}
     end

  end
```

but I am catching always a failure, meaning I am catching an error. Although I am sending success => true

Comment: Rails tries to show a template that doesn't exists? You could check your controllers actions respond to json.

Comment: I know but I do not understand why he complains about it, I am rendering a   json, so it should be good, no?

Answer (score 0):

You have two mistakes:

First, `val` is a function, so you should call `$(this).val()` to get the selected option.

Second, the error you are getting is because ajax requests are `format.js` by default, not `format json`, so your controller is looking for `group_name_exists.js.erb`, which doesn't exist. You should respond to `format.js` with something, or create that view.

Comment: I tried: format.js { render :json => { :success => false} } it still complains, or with what should I respond then if I want to catch a success=> false in ajax?

Comment: Does the corresponding tempalte exists? What was the error?

Comment: I do not need a corresponding template because I am responding to format with a json

Comment: Please post your actual code if what I said isn't working. Your code as posted should cause a syntax error because you are missing an `end`. Also, if you indent correctly it will be much easier.